# Yii2 active form submit event invoked twice

Tags: jquery, yii2, active-form

> This question had been asked before that question:
>   [Prevent multiple clicks and ActiveForm submission in Yii 2.0.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637656/prevent-multiple-clicks-and-activeform-submission-in-yii-2-0-10)

**Symptoms**

I have an active form with `id` equals to `surasGo`. I attached `submit` event using Jquery to handle some tasks before submit. I noticed that any `alert` function in the event function is produced twice. I checked out the page HTML source and I found the following snippets:

```
...
jQuery('#surasGo').yiiActiveForm([], []);
});</script></body>
```

before the previous snippet there is linked javascript file contains my code:

```
$('#surasGo').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    suraId = $('#surasId').val()*1;
    verseId = $('#versesId').val()*1;   
    if (!isNaN(verseId*1) && verseId !== 0){
      window.location = '/verses/view/'+verseId;
    }
    else if (!isNaN(suraId) && suraId !== 0){
      window.location = '/view/'+suraId;
    }
    else{
      alert(tError+"\n"+tQAccessError);// this alerted twice for example
    }
    return false;
  });
```

**What I have tried**

I realized that the first snippet `jQuery('#surasGo').yiiActiveForm([], []);` may be responsible for the double invoke of submit events due to active form client validation so I added `'enableClientValidation'=>false` property to the active form:

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'surasGo','enableClientValidation'=>false, 'action'...
```

However, the form is still seems to be undergo to submit event twice! What is the cause of this weird behavior and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you try `$('body').on('submit', '#surasGo', function(e) {<yourcode>})`

Comment: @jagsler Yes I have tried it as you suggested and it works fine. However, what's the reason that make my way `$('#surasGo').submit(...` re-apply the event twice?

Comment: No idea... had the exact same problem. Took me forever to find this solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent multiple clicks and ActiveForm submission in Yii 2.0.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637656/prevent-multiple-clicks-and-activeform-submission-in-yii-2-0-10)

Comment: @JairusMartin Please checkout the quote edit of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you also need to stop executing any downstream chain of event handlers. This can be done by calling `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in addition to `event.preventDefault().`

**Try like this :**

```
$('#surasGo').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // this is required in some cases
    suraId = $('#surasId').val()*1;
    verseId = $('#versesId').val()*1;   
    if (!isNaN(verseId*1) && verseId !== 0){
      window.location = '/verses/view/'+verseId;
    }
    else if (!isNaN(suraId) && suraId !== 0){
      window.location = '/view/'+suraId;
    }
    else{
      alert(tError+"\n"+tQAccessError);// this alerted twice for example
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting `'validateOnSubmit' => false` for the `ActiveForm` worked for me:

`$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'my-form-id', 'validateOnSubmit' => false]);`

Comment: Worked for me too!

Answer (score 2):

**Works Like a Charm**

I implemented and tested the following extension:

https://github.com/Faryshta/yii2-disable-submit-buttons

**Composer Require**

`"faryshta/yii2-disable-submit-buttons": "*"`

**Register Asset Globaly**

```
class AppAsset extends yii\web\AssetBundle
{
    public $depends = [
        'faryshta\\assets\\ActiveFormDisableSubmitButtonsAsset',
        // other dependencies
    ];
}
```

**Usage**

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => ['class' => 'disable-submit-buttons'],
    // other configurations
]);

    // inputs

    Html::submitButton('Submit', [
        // optional, will show the value of `data-disabled-text` attribute
        // while handling the validation and submit
        'data' => ['disabled-text' => 'Please Wait']
    ])

$form->end();
```

Comment: People suggested updating to Yii2 2.0.10, which has a supposed fix but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return boolean false in "beforeValidate" method, like here:

```
$(document).on("beforeValidate", "#form_id", function (event, messages) {
      //console.log('beforeValidate');
      return false;
    });
```